How to parse a string with numbers delimited by comma to int Array?
I have the following string with numbers delimited by a comma. The string is obtained from an Entry widget. How can I parse it to an int vector?
from tkinter import *

def key_return(event):
    stringToParse= String_entry.get()
    print(stringToParse) # which basically looks like this '110,220,330'


root = Tk()

global stringToParse

# Creating Entry widget
String_entry  = Entry(root, width=20, font= ('Helvetica 13'))
String_entry.insert(INSERT, "insert text")

# Pressing enter to get the widget string
String_entry.bind('<Return>', key_return)

String_entry.pack()
root.mainloop()


...some function to parse....
print(parsedString)

I basically need the following output as int vector:
# Output
# 
# [110,220,330]


FYI, the statement global stringToParse is useless when it's in the global scope. Perhaps you wanted to put it at the start of your ker_return function

Yes, you are right. I am used with C++ where when you enter a local function, all variables defined there are local to that function.

Is this what you need?
from tkinter import *

def key_return(event):
    stringToParse= String_entry.get()
    intList = [int(x) for x in stringToParse.split(',')]
    print(intList)


root = Tk()

String_entry  = Entry(root, width=20, font= ('Helvetica 13'))
String_entry.insert(INSERT, "insert text")

String_entry.bind('<Return>', key_return)

String_entry.pack()
root.mainloop() 


You can use the built in map function to process each element in sequence. In this case use split to separate each number in the string, and int to convert each one to an integer as follows:
stringToParse = '110,220,330' # the captured text
numbers = list(map(int, stringToParse.split(','))) # return a list of the values
print(numbers)


Using str as a variable name is ill-advised

@SIGHUP Thanks, I was doing this in too much of a hurry.

Don't use wildcard imports.
Make sure you handle data that can't be converted to int.
from tkinter import Entry, INSERT, Tk

def key_return(_):
    stringToParse= String_entry.get()
    _list = []
    try:
        _list = [int(x) for x in stringToParse.split(',')]
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print(_list)


root = Tk()

String_entry  = Entry(root, width=20, font= ('Helvetica 13'))
String_entry.insert(INSERT, "insert text")
String_entry.bind('<Return>', key_return)
String_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()

